# Which step am I messing up with this integration by parts problem?

Tags: integration

I'm having issues with a dozen or so integration problems, but I'll start with this one. I'll try and post one at a time until it is solved and then move onto the next one.

$$\int_\frac{1}{12}^\frac{1}{4}  \frac{1}{\sqrt{x} * (4x + 1)}$$

Here are the steps I take.

- **Step 1.** Set $$ u = \sqrt{x} $$  which means  $$ u^2 = x $$
- **Step 2.** $$2u du = dx$$
- **Step 3.** $$ \int_\frac{1}{12}^\frac{1}{4} \frac{2u du}{u(4x+1)} $$
- **Step 4.** Cancel out the u which give $$ \int_\frac{1}{12}^\frac{1}{4} \frac{2 du}{(4x+1)} $$

I stopped there because to me it doesn't look like I'm going in the right direction. Why would I cancel out the u if the whole point of it is to use it for substitution? Should it be

$$ \int_\frac{1}{12}^\frac{1}{4} \frac{u du}{(4x+1)} $$

rather than cancelling out the 2?

I would appreciate it someone could tell me what I should be doing.

Comment: Are you allowed to use $\int \frac{1}{1+u^2}\ du=\tan^{-1}(u)+C$?

Comment: Why do you want to do integration by parts? Just a thought, substitution method (take out the radical) might work too. That 4x needs to be replaced by variable u as well

Comment: @Rebecca I'm allowed to use any method necessary, I just thought the proper way would be IBP. Judging by the replies, I am incorrect.

Comment: You've done most of the work already then; amWhy's answer explains how to finish it off, then just use the above integral.

Comment: @Rebecca Thank you for pointing that out, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no real need to perform integration by parts, here. Rather, we proceed with substitution. You've done fine, up through step $(4)$, almost. Given where you got to, at step $(4)$:
$$\int_\frac{1}{12}^\frac{1}{4} \frac{2 du}{(4x+1)}$$

We first need to replace $4x + 1$ in the denominator by it's equivalent, with $4u^2 + 1 = (2u)^2 + 1$.

We need also to change the bounds of integration. $$\text{When }\,x = \dfrac 14, \;u = \sqrt{\dfrac 14} = \dfrac 12.\quad\text{When }\;x = \frac 1{12},\; u = \sqrt{\frac{1}{12}} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt 3}$$

$$\int_{\large \frac{1}{2\sqrt 3}}^{\large \frac 12} \frac{2\, du}{(2u)^2 + 1} = \tan^{-1}\left(2u\right)\Huge|_{\large \frac{1}{2\sqrt 3}}^{\large \frac 12}$$

Comment: I'm slightly upset, I would have never realized that $ \int \frac{2du}{(2u)^2 + 1} $ is integrated to arctan(2u). Thank you for the explanation, I need to review my inverse trig functions a bit so I don't get stumped by them.

Comment: You're welcome! You might want to begin your review [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trig_substitution#Integrals_containing_a2_.2B_x2)

Comment: Thank you! I'll definitely read into it before I post my next question. (some of my questions deal with trig sub)

Comment: @amWhy: Needs a UV to go with the check +1